# Jquery: prevent submit after for validation

Tags: jquery

Formvalidator plugin submits the form after form validation. I want to prevent the form submission after validation and call the function offerpricepopup(), in this function I submit the form. But this is not happening the form automatically submits after form validation.

```
  var sss = $('#submitBtn1').formValidator({
            onSuccess   : function() { console.log('Success!'); 
                        },
            scope       : '#postform',
            errorDiv    : '#errorDiv1'
        });

  $("#postform").on("submit", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       offerpricepopup();

    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try validate first then call your method then submit it.

Comment: maybe a `return false;` in the onSuccess:function(){}

Comment: @john Smith no that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a different function to validate. Looking through the documentation, it looks like there is a way to only check and see if the form validates without submitting. I found a description of that here (second one down) http://www.formvalidator.net/#advanced